# MySQL Date Format Convert Hour-Minute to Interval and Disregard Year-Month-Day

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

(Sorry, I initially thought this was MySQL, got my DB's mixed up, working in too many DBMS at the same time)

I need to compare an event's half-way midpoint between a start and stop time of day. Right now i'm converting the dates you see on the right, to HH:MM and the comparison works until midnight.

the query says: WHERE half BETWEEN pStart and pStop.

As you can see below, pStart and pStap have January 1st 2000 dates, this is because the year month day are not important to me...

**Valid Data:**

```
 +-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
 | half  | pStart | pStop | half2               | pStart2             | pStop2              |
 +-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
 | 19:00 | 19:00  | 23:00 | 2012-11-04 19:00:00 | 2000-01-01 19:00:00 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 |
 | 20:00 | 19:00  | 23:00 | 2012-11-04 20:00:00 | 2000-01-01 19:00:00 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 |
 | 21:00 | 19:00  | 23:00 | 2012-11-04 21:00:00 | 2000-01-01 19:00:00 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 |
 | 23:00 | 20:00  | 23:00 | 2012-11-05 23:00:00 | 2000-01-01 20:00:00 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 |
 +-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Now observe what happens when pStop is midnight or later...

**Valid Data that breaks it:**

```
+-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| half  | pStart | pStop | half2               | pStart2             | pStop2              |
+-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
| 23:00 | 22:00  | 00:00 | 2012-11-04 23:00:00 | 2000-01-01 22:00:00 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 23:30 | 23:00  | 02:00 | 2012-11-05 23:30:00 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 | 2000-01-01 02:00:00 |
+-------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Thus my where clause translates to: 
*WHERE 19:00 BETWEEN 22:00 AND 00:00* ...which returns false and I miss those two correct rows above.

**Question:**

Is there a way to show those dates as integer interval so that saying half BETWEEN pStart and pStop are correct?

I thought about adding 24 when pStop is less than pStart to make 00:00 into 24:00 but don't know an easy way to do that without long string concatenations and number conversions. This would solve the problem because pStart pStop difference will never be longer than 6 hours.

Note: (The Query is much more complex. It has other irrelevant date calculations, but the result are show above. DATE_FORMAT(%H:%i) is applied to the first three columns and no formatting to the last three)

Thanks for your help:

Comment: Possible Solution: Is there a way to replace the year-month-day on a timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

So the day is important to you then?

Given you've messed it up by doing everything in one day, it's going to have to be something like

```
WHere ((Start <= Stop) and ??)
Or
((Start > Stop) and ???)
```

Comment: Well the day is important in the sense tomorrow should be greater. Really doesn't matter. the date January First 2000 is insignificant. only the hour is important.

edit: actually minute is important too.

Comment: Can't agree. It would have been easier to have kept the date, and as soon as you spanned midnight once (what happens if your range went over 24 hours?) the argument for not doing so was in the bin. Now you are desperately bodging to rescue a poor design. In my experience that tends to be a really bad idea. One thing you could have done instead, would have been start time and duration in minutes. I learnt not to do this sort of thing in a lot harder way. British Summer Time. Start 01:50, End 03:00, Duration 2:10, 1:10 or 0:10, depending on what day it was...